# Bluetooth setting not working properly in cinnamon

Tags: unity, 16.04, bluetooth, cinnamon

I had installed cinnamon desktop on ubuntu 16.04 some weeks ago and have been using it as default since then, without any problem. But today i noticed a problem- the bluetooth setting doesnot work properly.

In System Settings>Networking>Bluetooth, it always show OFF (although in my phone it says connected to my laptop). When i try to change it to ON, it says *'connecting'* for a few seconds and then changes to OFF again.

But in reality, the bluetooth is on no matter what the settings say. Because in my phone it shows that the laptop is connected and also whenever i play audio in my phone the sound always comes out of my laptop.

*This problem is not present in Unity. In Unity there is a bluetooth icon in the top bar. I can see and connect to either of my paired devices (phone or tablet) and sent files to them.*

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install blueberry
```

It says that when you add the Cinnamon repository.

I have just done this and successfully connected.